# Dual-boot Win 10 + Ubuntu using Grub -- cannot start Ubuntu after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10, initramfs

I've been running an Ubuntu WUBI "partition" on my Win 10 machine for 5 years now, first with 16.04 LTS, then with 18.04, with no problems. Today I tried up upgrade to 20.04 LTS, and while rebooting during installation, GRUB -> Ubuntu Recovery failed to a BusyBox v1.30.1 (initramfs) prompt. I can't get past that prompt to get Ubuntu to boot.

```
 No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

I've noticed on some passes that it's expecting init in /sbin/init, but my init file is at /init.

I've also tried booting via the GRUB Console, but I'm having trouble locating where my root should be. Using the excellent guide found here https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/  it seems to be on a (loop0) partition. But when I try to modify the following commands

```
 grub> set root=(loop0)
 grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic root=/dev/loop0
 grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-64-generic
 grub> boot
```

It fails. My root.disk file is on (hd1,4)/ubuntu/disks/root.disk, so I tried this for line two:

```
 grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-64-generic root=/dev/sda4 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
```

But that also failed, saying there was no file at /hosts/ubuntu/disks/root.disk. (It added "/hosts" somehow). I think my root.disk isn't being properly mounted in /dev, but not sure why it's appearing as loop0. Not sure what to do next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I suspect it's something basic I've overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: LInk does not show loop at all. If you are seeing loop that is from the installer, not from an install, and how you can directly boot an ISO. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After two days of trying to understand GRUB and initramfs I gave up, mounted my Ubuntu WUBI root.disk file using an Ubuntu ISO installer and offloaded all my important files before re-installing WUBI on Win10. Everything works fine now; I suspect the issue was the older version of WUBI I was using (which I had installed back when I was using Ubuntu 16.04), which had somehow survived my upgrade to 18.04, but finally puked on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Wubi has not been supported since 12.04, although still in some later distributions. Users now just use live installer in live mode from flash drive for testing. Or do a full install to external drive.